# I'm looking for real-life example of React testing with Jest & Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, git, github, jestjs, enzyme

I know my question is very abstract, but I'm struggling to understand what exactly should/shouldn't be tested in React app.

What I'm looking for:
Something like Git repository of popular project with advanced react&jest&enzyme tests that I can take as a real-life example.

Thank you!

Comment: `react-select`: https://github.com/react-component/select/blob/68bf5fe7e93e5a683d765762f028c1822399c776/tests/Select.spec.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is a partial answer that may help. I just posted **3/21/19** [react native structure](https://github.com/HBDunn/rnstruct):

A **React React-Native Webpack Typescript Jest TravisCI** shared code-base.

The jest testing is actually just on the react parts which are the 
files without .native. or .ios. or .android. see the `__tests__` directory.

The jest config is in the *package.json* file.

Run the 'test-local' script:
`npm run test-local`

I haven't gotten to enzyme yet, but there is good material, that I have not tested like [jest-enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-enzyme) and others, to google.